# Mutli column and mutl table inner join

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I need to perform inner-join on tables with two common columns org_id and time_stamp on data in avro format in S3 queried through Athena

I have tried

```
SELECT year(from_iso8601_timestamp(em.time_stamp)) time_unit,
         sum(em.column1) column1,
         sum(spa.column2) column2,
         sum(vir.column3) column3
FROM "schemaName".table1 em
JOIN "schemaName".table2 spa
    ON year(from_iso8601_timestamp(em.time_stamp)) = year(from_iso8601_timestamp(spa.time_stamp))
        AND em.org_id = spa.org_id
JOIN "schemaName".table3 vir
    ON year(from_iso8601_timestamp(vir.time_stamp)) = year(from_iso8601_timestamp(spa.time_stamp))
        AND vir.org_id = spa.org_id
WHERE em.org_id = 'org_id_test'
        AND (from_iso8601_timestamp(em.time_stamp)) <= (cast(from_iso8601_timestamp('2019-11-22T23:59:31') AS timestamp))
        AND (from_iso8601_timestamp(em.time_stamp)) >= (cast(from_iso8601_timestamp('2019-11-22T23:59:31') AS timestamp) - interval '10' year)
GROUP BY  em.org_id, year(from_iso8601_timestamp(em.time_stamp))
ORDER BY  time_unit DESC limit 11
```

But what I am getting is kind of looking as cross-join

```
results
    time_unit   |column1    |column2    |column3
1   2019        |48384      |299040     |712
```

while if I aggregate on each table separately with same where conditions, then values appear as

```
table1
column1

    504
```

```
table2
column2

    280
```

```
table3
column3

    5
```

can somebody help me figure out what I am doing wrong and right way to achieve it?

Comment: No, "somebody" cannot help, because we cannot see the data and see what *you* mean by "cross join".  I would suggest simplifying the query (removing tables and columns) to get a smaller example that shows the problem.  Then, ask a *new* question with sample data and desired results.  How you see a "cross join" when only returning 11 rows is somewhat mysterious to me.

Comment: let me add some data

Comment: why use cross-join??? cross-join haven't logic... i guess you need left join

Comment: @GordonLinoff Please have a look now, thanks for the patience

Comment: @Amirhossein No, I am not using cross join though it appears from the output as if it's happening so.

Comment: is not clear you expected  result  ..  add your expected  result as tabular text ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* I followed you correctly, what is happening is that, since there are multiple records matching the conditions in each join, you end up the same record being counted multiple time when you aggregate.

A typical way around this is to aggregate in subqueries, and then join.

Something like this might be what you are looking for:

```
select 
    em.time_unit,
    em.column1,
    spa.column2,
    vir.column3
from (
    select 
        org_id,
        year(from_iso8601_timestamp(time_stamp)) time_unit,
        sum(column1) column1
    from "schemaname".table1
    group by org_id, year(from_iso8601_timestamp(time_stamp))
) em
join (
    select 
        org_id,
        year(from_iso8601_timestamp(time_stamp)) time_unit,
        sum(column2) column2
    from "schemaname".table2
    group by org_id, year(from_iso8601_timestamp(time_stamp))
) spa on spa.time_unit = em.time_unit and spa.org_id = em.org_id
join (
    select 
        org_id,
        year(from_iso8601_timestamp(time_stamp)) time_unit,
        sum(column3) column3
    from "schemaname".table3
    group by org_id, year(from_iso8601_timestamp(time_stamp))
) vir on vir.time_unit = em.time_unit and vir.org_id = em.org_id
where 
    em.org_id = 'org_id_test'
    and em.time_unit between 2009 and 2019
order by em.time_unit desc 
limit 11
```

Comment: You have understood the problem the solution worked like a charm thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome @piyushtyagi! Glad that it helped.